# jquery $.ajax behaves differently in iframe and non-iframe

Tags: jquery

I have `script.html`, which submits a POST ajax. with following alert messages

`success: alert("success");`

I load `script.html` in an `iframe` on `index.html`. AJAX post is successful. Firebug throws no error. However, I dont see success alert message.

I load `script.html` by itself. AJAX post is successful. Success Alert Message pops up.

please help. I need to load `script.html` via `iframe`.

Comment: Can you post a cutdown version of the code you use in your iframe and index.html? You are including the jquery JS file in both right?

Answer (score 0):

Does the iframe come from the same domain as index.html? You might be running into cross-site scripting security restrictions.

Are you able to tell on the server if the ajax call has been received from the iframe (by logging it or just looking at the access logs)? This should help narrow it down.